# How to set and access a "global" logger in Go?

Tags: go, logging

I am sure there's some simple, fundamental issue I'm missing, I'm very new to go. **How do I set up a logger so it can be shared between functions, assuming I do not want to use the default logger?**

### `logissue.go`

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/pkg/errors"
  "log"
  "os"
)

var dlog log.Logger

const logfile string = "killer.log"
const logprefix string = "LOGTEST: "

func setupLogger(filename, prefix string) (*log.Logger, error) {
  out, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "can't open logfile for writing")
  }
  return log.New(out, prefix, log.LstdFlags), nil
}

func uselog() error {
  fmt.Printf("%T\n", dlog)
  dlog.Printf("Hello")            ///// < Here is the issue
  return nil
}

func main() {
  dlog, err := setupLogger(logfile, logprefix)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%+v", err)
  }
  dlog.Printf("test from main")
  uselog()
}
```

### `stdout`

```
log.Logger
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x10970b8]

goroutine 1 [running]:
log.(*Logger).Output(0x116dd00, 0x2, 0xc000016106, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/log/log.go:172 +0x1e8
log.(*Logger).Printf(0x116dd00, 0x10c9202, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/log/log.go:179 +0x7e
main.uselog(0xc000088050, 0x10ca43b)
    /Users/sequoia/learning/Ex_Files_Go_EssT/Exercise Files/logissue.go:25 +0xc4
main.main()
    /Users/sequoia/learning/Ex_Files_Go_EssT/Exercise Files/logissue.go:35 +0xee
exit status 2
```

### `killer.log`

```
LOGTEST: 2019/02/17 18:25:12 test from main
```

Comment: So first of all based on your code above you're trying to set a non-pointer logger with a pointer logger which wont work. Secondly you're using := when setting dlog which creates a scoped variable in your main method rather than setting your global variable.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to fix it! Can you put this in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've added it as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all based on your code above you're trying to set a non-pointer logger with a pointer logger which wont work. Secondly you're using := when setting dlog which creates a scoped variable in your main method rather than setting your global variable

Answer (score -2):

I tried this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "log"
    "os"
)

const logfile string = "killer.log"
const logprefix string = "LOGTEST: "

var DLog *log.Logger
func setupLogger(filename, prefix string) {
    var err error
    out, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal( nil, errors.Wrap(err, "can't open logfile for writing"))
    }
    DLog=log.New(out, prefix, log.LstdFlags)

    fmt.Println("Log object: ",DLog)

}

func uselog() error {
    DLog.Print("Hello") ///// < Here is the issue
    DLog.Print("I have something standard to say")

    fmt.Println("I am done")
    return nil
}

func main() {
    setupLogger(logfile, logprefix)
    DLog.Printf("test from main")
    uselog()
}
```